# Passing pipeline value as parameter to xargs for use by eval echo

Tags: bash, pipe, xargs

I have a text file that I'm using as a template, it looks like this:

```
Hostname     : $HOSTNAME
Host Address : $HOSTADDRESS
```

My bash script sets two variables, `HOSTNAME` and `HOSTADDRESS`, reads the template file then does an `eval` to expand `$HOSTNAME` and `$HOSTADDRESS`:

```
HOSTNAME="SH_SQL_0089"
HOSTADDRESS="172.16.3.44"
TEMPLATE=`cat template.txt`
MESSAGE=`eval echo $TEMPLATE`
```

The resultant value of `MESSAGE` is:

```
Hostname     : SH_SQL_0089
Host Address : 172.16.3.44
```

Is it possible to reduce the last two lines to something like:

```
MESSAGE=$(cat template.txt | eval echo ????)
```

I tried using `xargs`:

```
MESSAGE=$( cat template.txt | xargs -i bash -c "eval echo {}" )
```

But it only substitutes `$HOSTNAME` and strips the carriage returns.

The reason I want to do this is that I need to add a third processing step and pipe the `eval`'d output to that. I feel I'm so close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `xargs` can't work here because the substitutions would be executed in a subprocess (the `bash` processes that `xargs` launches). But only environment variables are passed to subprocesses, not shell variables. Evidently `HOSTNAME` was already in your script's environment when it started, but `HOSTADDRESS` isn't. At this point you might be tempted to export all variables, but even then `xargs` isn't a good solution because it suffers from numerous quoting issues − if your template contains `\"'` or if you want to retain whitespace, you're toast.

Now, looking at your current code: `` MESSAGE=`eval echo $TEMPLATE` `` is a complex way of writing `eval MESSAGE=$TEMPLATE`, except for quoting issues. And you do have quoting issues; for example you'll have noticed that all your whitespace has been collapsed. You've heard of [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/), haven't you? Shell expansion rules are pretty complex, but there are some rules that'll keep you sane:

- Always double quotes around variable substitutions `"$foo"` and command substitutions `"$(bar)"`. You may violate this rule if you understand why you need to omit the quotes.
- Use `$(…)` rather than `` `…` `` for command substitutions. Quoting inside the backquote form is arcane and not portable, whereas quoting inside `$(…)` works normally.
- Use `eval` only if pressed at gunpoint. If you do, be very careful, and make it as simple as possible.

So what can go wrong with `eval MESSAGE="$TEMPLATE"`? It makes the shell evaluate

```
MESSAGE=Hostname     : $HOSTNAME
Host Address : $HOSTADDRESS
```

Oops, we need quotes around the part that should be the value of `MESSAGE`. The quotes have to get through to `eval`, so they need to go literally through the first stage of shell expansion: `eval MESSAGE="\"$TEMPLATE\""`.

```
MESSAGE="Hostname     : $HOSTNAME
Host Address : $HOSTADDRESS"
```

Better, but now you have exactly the Bobby Tables injection pattern — what if the template contains a quote? Then you need to escape the quotes. The four characters that have a special meaning between double quotes are `` \"$` ``, and you want `$` to retain its meaning, so add a backslash before the other three.

```
TEMPLATE=$(sed -e 's/[\\"`]/\\&/g' <template.txt)
eval MESSAGE="\"$TEMPLATE\""
```

Now the shell will evaluate

```
MESSAGE="Hostname     : $HOSTNAME
Host Address : $HOSTADDRESS
Name         : Bobby \"drop\" O'Tables"
```

and all's good.

Note that proper quoting here is to protect against accidental parsing problems; whoever controls the template still has shell access (with `$(hello)`).

If you wanted the template included in your shell script, this would be naturally done with a [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

```
MESSAGE=$(cat <<EOF)
Hostname     : $HOSTNAME
Host Address : $HOSTADDRESS
EOF
```

But with an external template you'd need to do two steps of evaluation, hence use `eval`, and bash's parsing is quite buggy when it comes to funky stuff like heredocs inside `eval`. There's surely a way that works, at least with bash 4, but I don't recommend risking it.

Comment: How about export $(cat .env | xargs)?

Comment: @kta I have no idea what you're trying to do with this command. What's `.env`? Why are you using `cat`? What's the point of invoking `xargs` without a command?

Answer (score 2):

You want the shell to apply substitutions of variables, which means
that the template text must be read by the shell itself as part of a
command, but the template is also multi-line text so it's a bit tricky
to get into the line-oriented processing normally done by UNIX
commands.

One approach would be to use bash [here-documents](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) (all commands shown
as typed at the shell prompt):

1. create the template file:

   ```
   $ cat template.txt
   Hi, $NAME

   Welcome to $PLACE
   ```
2. [export](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html) the variables that should be substituted in the template
   text:

   ```
   $ export NAME=Bob
   $ export PLACE='unix&linux'
   ```
3. create a shell variable that holds a single "newline" `\n`
   character; in bash the easiest way is to simply open a string, type
   a newline and close it:

   ```
   $ newline='
   > '
   ```
4. finally, call bash to do the substitution:

   ```
   $ bash -c "cat <<__EOF__${newline}$(cat template.txt)${newline}__EOF__"
   Hi, Bob

   Welcome to unix&linux
   ```

Why does this work? Let's deconstruct it from the bottom:
you're asking bash to execute a command (by the `-c` option), but
the variable substitution `${newline}` and the command expansion
`$(cat ...)` happen in the parent shell before `bash -c ...` is
actually executed.  So the result is that `bash -c` sees a command
string that embeds newlines and the whole template text.  It's as if
you had typed the following at a bash prompt:

```
cat <<__EOF__
...contents of template.txt...
__EOF__
```

Also note that the substitution variables need to be exported, since
the variables are assigned in the parent shell but it's the "child"
bash that is doing the substitution.

**Note**, however, that this approach can easily lead to quoting issues: since the template text is interpreted by the bash shell, [backtics](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) are expanded, which might result in commands being executed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

You might even (double) `eval` an embedded single-quoted string for experiment's sake:

```
export HOSTNAME HOSTADDRESS
(
NL='
'
DELIM=$'\177'
esc="'\''"
export IFS=""
HOSTNAME="SH_SQL_00'8'9"
HOSTADDRESS='172.16.3.44 Bobby "drop" O'\''Tables ${PWD} $(ls)'
printf '%s\n' 'Hostname : $HOSTNAME' 'Host Address : $HOSTADDRESS' > template.txt
TEMPLATE="$(<template.txt)"
TEMPLATE="${TEMPLATE//\'/${esc}}"       # escape every single quote: ' --> '\'' (which later will become ''\''' by '${TEMPLATE}')
TEMPLATE="${TEMPLATE//${NL}/${DELIM}}"  # replace every newline char with a delim char
evalstr="echo '${TEMPLATE}'"
#printf '\n%s\n\n' "${evalstr}" | LC_ALL=C vis -fotc
set -xv
eval eval "${evalstr}"
) | LC_ALL=C tr '\177' '\n' | nl
```

Answer (score -2):

```
MESSAGE=$(eval $(cat template.txt))
```

Comment: I think you meant `$(eval echo $(cat ...` - but that would collapse the text into a single line.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant, but it's not going to help Kev write working code.

Comment: Gilles: I think my solution is working, with the echo mentioned by Riccardo, and I think it was the answer for his question... Anyway she/he got a solution already :)